# How to layout items in hexagonal grids to maximize the sum of similarities between all adjacent items?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, layout, graph, combinations

I have some items, each pair of them share a similarity belongs to [0,1], namely, there is a similarity matrix.

I want to layout these items in hexagonal grids, holding a one-to-one correspondence between items and hexagonal grids. Then items form a area in which some of them share the adjacent relationship.

My question is how to layout to make the sum of adjacent similarity maximum.(see the figure below: the red line is the boundary of one layout example, the blue is the adjacent edge I concern). Is there any algorithm can solve above problem?

I think it's similar to Minimum Spanning Tree problem, but it seems much more complicated, maybe a NP-hard problem but I am not sure. So whether exists an algorithm to get the global optimization in polynomial time as prim or Kruskal algorithm dose?

Further, what if there exists a constrain that the layout must be limited in a fixed area, e.g. the area bounded by yellow line in figure(of course, the number of items is less than the the number of hexagons that the area contains).

One more step, dose it matter if similarity belongs to [-1,1] for your algorithm?

[image: the figure]